# Make div height stretch to parent remaining space and make it scrollable

Tags: css

I have the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oLq00r4k/), and basically my goal is to make the `.dialog_list > .list` element fit into the `dialog-wrap` and become scrollable. At first, I thought I would be easy to achieve with some sort of `overflow-y: auto;`, but I had no success. I am new to advanced CSS and I've read through the doc regarding CSS flex-box several times, experimented with positions (relative, absolute) as well as bottom/top/left/right, but each time I have weirdly looking results. Help me please!

NOTE!

If I change

```
.dialog_wrap > .dialog_list {
  width: 430px;
  border-right-style: solid;

}
```

to

```
.dialog_wrap > .dialog_list {
      width: 430px;
      border-right-style: solid;
      overflow-y: auto; 
    }
```

then I have satisfactory result, but the problem is that I don't want the heading to be in scrollable space. I want only `.dialog_wrap > .dialog_list > .list` to be scrollable, not `.dialog_wrap > .dialog_list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. You need to specify the height of the container so that `overflow` works (because if its height is not constrained, it will never overflow).

Here's the [updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/8L3qf9e8/1/). In this version, you **don't need to hardcode the list's height**. It will fill the remaining space and be scrollable, while the headers remain on top. This works by using `height: calc(100% - 50px);` on the `.list` and make it `overflow: auto`. Further you need to make sure the `.list-dialog` element has `height: 100%` as well, or else it will just grow and not make the `.list` overflow.

```css
* {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #e3e4e8;
}

.dialog_wrap {
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: red;
}

.dialog_wrap > .dialog_list {
  width: 430px;
  height: 100%;
  border-right-style: solid;
}

.dialog_wrap > .dialog_list > .heading {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.dialog_wrap > .dialog_list > .list {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.dialog_wrap > .dialog_list > .list ul {
  padding: 0 !important;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.dialog_wrap > .dialog_list > .list li > .dialog_instance {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px !important;
}

.dialog_wrap > .details {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.dialog_wrap > .details > .container {
  position: relative;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  padding: 0;
}

.dialog_wrap > .details > .container > .heading {
  height: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.dialog_wrap > .details > .container > .body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='dialog_wrap'>
  <div class='dialog_list'>
    <div class='heading'>
      <div>Section A</div>
    </div>
    <div class='list'>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class='dialog_instance'>
            <span>A</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class='dialog_instance'>
              <span>B</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class='dialog_instance'>
              <span>C</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class='dialog_instance'>
              <span>D</span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='details'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='heading'>
        Section B
      </div>
      <div class='body'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer. Special thanks for `calc` ) Did not know about it

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS:

```
.dialog_wrap > .dialog_list > .list {
  height: 90px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

.. with predefined height

Comment: Well, is it the cleanest solution? Having to manually set the height seems not good in terms of DRY. My div consists of two parts. And if I have hard-code the height of one of them, I would ideally like the second div to occupy the rest of the space

Comment: Then you need to use HTML table or CSS display table. First row will be static, the second will take the rest space

Comment: You don't necessarily need tables for that. Just constrain the height to `100%` and subtract the `50px` from the header as suggested in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try

overflow-y: scroll;

I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: No, `overflow-y: scroll;` would result in permanent scroll, no matter if the content is large enough to need scroll or not

Comment: That's right. I tried this in your JSFiddle. It worked for me: overflow: auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;